# React: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a React website and get following error message:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render, propTypes, displayName, onSubmit, Naked, options, useStyles}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
   in Unknown (at Landing/index.js:93)
   in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
   in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
   in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at Landing/index.js:88)
   in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
   in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
   in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at Landing/index.js:82)
   in Landingpage (created by WithStyles(Landingpage))
   in WithStyles(Landingpage) (created by Context.Consumer)
   in Route (at App.js:34)
   in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
   in BrowserRouter (at App.js:33)
   in App (at withRoot.js:12)
   in ThemeProvider (at withRoot.js:9)
   in WithRoot (at src/index.js:7)
```

I think this is related to me not using withroot while still calling props.history. However, I tried to change that by using the connect method, which also did not work as you can see here: [React: applying styles and using connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768286/react-applying-styles-and-using-connect)

Here you see my src/Landing/index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppContext from '../utils/AppContext';
import { Header } from '../Layout';
import SOSButton from './SOSButton';
import axios from 'axios';
import CONST from '../utils/Constants';

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    // background: 'white',
    border: 'black',
    'border-width': 'medium',
    'margin-top': '80px',
    background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    'border-radius': '20px'
  },
  item: {
    // background: 'red',
    width: '100%',
    //background: 'white',
    'text-align': 'center',
    'border-radius': '5px',
    'margin-top': '10px'
  },
  sosbutton: {
    background: 'red',
    'text-align': 'center',
    'margin-top': '30px',
    height: '80%',
    width: '100%'
  }
});

class Landingpage extends React.Component {
  static contextType = AppContext;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.classes = props.classes;
    this.state = {};
    this.handleDirectSOS = this.handleDirectSOS.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.context);

    if (this.context.onBoardingStatus === false) {
      console.log('IN IF');
      this.props.history.push('/onboarding');
    }
  }
  handleDirectSOS() {
    console.log('direct SOS');
    this.props.history.push('/emergency_sent');
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    console.log('in OnSubmit');
    axios
      .post(CONST.URL + 'emergency/create', {
        id: 1,
        data: this.state
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('direct SOS');
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header title="Send out SOS" />
        <Grid
          container
          className={this.classes.container}
          direction="column"
          spacing={2}
        >
          <Grid
            item
            sm={12}
            className={(this.classes.item, this.classes.forwardbutton)}
          >
            <SOSButton onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Landingpage);
```

Here you see my src/Landing/SOSButton.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
//import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
//import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const styles = theme => ({
  sosbutton: {
    background: 'e45050ff',
    'text-align': 'center',
    'margin-top': '30px',
    height: '80%',
    width: '100%'
  }
});

class SOSButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.classes = props.classes;
    this.state = {
      timerOn: false
    };
    this.timerStart = this.timerStart.bind(this);
    this.timerStop = this.timerStop.bind(this);
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
    this.counter = 3;
    this.counterStep = 1;
  }

  timerStart() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
    this.setState({ timerOn: true });
  }

  timerStop() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
    this.counter = 3;
    this.setState({ timerOn: false });
    this.props.history.push('/');
  }

  tick() {
    this.counter = this.counter - this.counterStep;
    if (this.counter <= 0) {
      this.setState({ timerOn: false });
      this.timerStop();
      this.props.onSubmit();
      this.props.history.push('/emergency_sent');
    } else {
      this.setState({ timerOn: true });
    }
    console.log(this.counter);
  }

  render() {
    let timerOn = this.state.timerOn;
    let button;

    if (timerOn) {
      button = (
        <div>
          You have {this.counter} seconds to cancel the emergency SOS. <br />
          <br />
          <Button size="large" color="primary" onClick={this.timerStop}>
            Press here to cancel emergency call!
          </Button>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      button = (
        <Button className={this.classes.sosbutton} onClick={this.timerStart}>
          GET HELP NOW!
        </Button>
      );
    }

    console.log(button);
    return button;
  }
}

//export default withRouter(connect()(withStyles(styles)(SOSButton)));
export default withStyles(SOSButton);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: i'm not quite sure, but in your SOSbutton in the return try `return {button}`

Comment: You shouldn't be doing `this.counter = this.counter - this.counterStep;`. These variables should be in the state.

Comment: @rebecca unfortunatelly return {button} did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

it could be because the items being rendered in the JSX Element are objects instead of primitives

Look into :: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/08/20/objects-not-valid-react-child/

Comment: Hm ok but which props would I need to define in either another component or separately?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on react-native and in my case I got the same error because I was missing some backticks ``.

So I had

```
export const Container = styled.SafeAreaView;
```

instead of

```
export const Container = styled.SafeAreaView``;
```